# Joomla! 403 error on SOME front-end pages

Tags: joomla, file-permissions

When I try to access two of my client's categories I get a "403 Forbidden" message. I searched SO and Joomla!'s official forums for an answer but so far I couldn't find anything related to the front end, only to some admin functions. I downloaded the site and the pages that weren't working on the server are working ok on my localhost. If I go to Directory Permissions in Joomla!'s backend it displays a red box saying "Unwritable" next to the Log and Temp directories. Checked on my host and they both have 755. What access should they have? Could it be some other problem?

Edit:
I managed to make those folders writable, apparently the problem was in the configuration.php script.

```
public $log_path = '../logs';
public $tmp_path = '../tmp';
```

This was the correct way they should haved been written. This still doesn't fix my problem so any help is still appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a solution sadly but I have the same problem.  I've searched for days for a solution and am at a loss. I upgraded to Joomla 3.4.0 although problem existed before the upgrade.
Mine only happens when attempting to edit certain articles from the front-end.  I've checked ACL and User has Publisher privileges and can successfully edit some pages but others cause 403 Forbidden after attempting to save changes even though they have the same category.
I tried replacing the article with a duplicate and gave it a different alias but it still wouldn't allow edits.

Have you checked the content > category manager > permissions for that user group on the problem category?

Comment: In my case I just created those categories again and basically copy/pasted all the articles inside them to recreate the pages. Then I added them in the menu and I solved the problem, still have no clue why it happened. It might have something to do with the alias generating a too long URL?